# Pixel conversion in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

Not exactly sure how to word the title to something like this but basically, I have a picturebox which represents a zoomed in version of an image and I have grid drawn on the box via pen. Between each box in the grid there is 8 pixels. When I move the mouse across the picturebox, I have a label that reads its e.x and e.y so its reading back the actual pixels I am moving my mouse over. But what I want it to do is to count it as one pixel for every box in the grid. So every 8x8 pixels reads a value of 1. I think it can be done with a for each loop but I am not sure how to go about this. Any ideas? Thanks.
These boxes are to represent each pixel of the zoomed in image so if the picturebox is actually 256 pixels wide, the image its representing is actually 32 pixels wide.

Comment: Access? Excel? Where does this form live?

Comment: visual basic. thats what i said in the title.

Comment: but your tag says VBA which only exists in another app. So if it's not VBA then does "Visual Basic" = VB6 or VB.NET? If VB.NET is the form WinForms, WPF, or some webcontrol?

Comment: sorry. i did not know that. i thought vb.net was the website version of vb code as i find in my searches so i thought vba meant visual basic app as in just visual basic. I am using Visual Basic 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use integer division to divide both the X and Y values by 8.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("X: {0}, Y: {1}", (e.X \ 8) + 1, (e.Y \ 8) + 1))
End Sub
```

Comment: Dude, Thank you! I was trying to think of a simple math equation that would do it but I just kept drawing a blank. But this worked. Sweet. Thank you so much.

Comment: Not a problem. I know exactly how it is sometimes when you get those mental blocks :)

Comment: so, mathematically, the number returned might be 1.875 for instance, but since its an integer, it comes back as a whole number instead? Because 15 divided by 8 is 1.875 so after adding 1, it is returned as an integer it comes back 2 instead of 2.875?

Comment: Since you're using \ instead of /, it returns an integer instead of a floating point number. It's the same thing as casting the answer to an int.

Comment: oh crap i had no idea about that. thanks for letting me know. uhm how do i do that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you in time, but it looks like you figured it out :)